# HystrixTimer - Failed while ticking TimerListener

Tags: java, concurrency, hystrix

I'm trying to use Hystrix Collapser command. My command takes a list of numbers as input, does a network call and returns the results. If the input list size is less than 5, the collapser command executes fine and i get the results back. If the input size increases, lets say to 50, i get the above exception, say after 10th or 12th request is executed. Here is the setter for hystrix properties. The collapser properties pretty default and request scoped.

```
Setter.withGroupKey(HystrixCommandGroupKey.Factory
                        .asKey("GroupKey"))
                .andCommandKey(HystrixCommandKey.Factory
                        .asKey("CommandKey"))
                .andThreadPoolKey(
                        HystrixThreadPoolKey.Factory.asKey("MyPool"))
                .andThreadPoolPropertiesDefaults(HystrixThreadPoolProperties.Setter().withCoreSize(15)
                        .withMaxQueueSize(50).withQueueSizeRejectionThreshold(50))
                .andCommandPropertiesDefaults(
                        HystrixCommandProperties.Setter().withExecutionTimeoutInMilliseconds(6000)
                                .withFallbackEnabled(false).withExecutionIsolationThreadInterruptOnTimeout(false))
```

please help me understand what is missing with config?
Sample stacktrace

```
2018-01-09 19:17:54,347 [HystrixTimer-2] [] [] [] [] [] (com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer) ERROR - Failed while ticking TimerListener
java.lang.RuntimeException: rx.exceptions.OnErrorNotImplementedException: CommandKey timed-out and fallback disabled.
at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextRunnable.run(HystrixContextRunnable.java:59)
at com.netflix.hystrix.AbstractCommand$HystrixObservableTimeoutOperator$2.tick(AbstractCommand.java:976)
at com.netflix.hystrix.util.HystrixTimer$1.run(HystrixTimer.java:100)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:304)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have missing configuration

https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1554

> - coreSize: minimum number of worker threads that the ExecutorService
>     keeps alive
> - maximumSize: maximum number of worker threads that the
>     ExecutorService can use. This is bounded by the system capacity, which
>     if breached, causes the system to go crash.
> - maxQueueSize: maximum
>     number of Runnable task the ExecutorService can take in.

Also, I  am not seeing any of the collapser properties defined: maxRequestsInBatch, timerDelayInMilliseconds...

Hystix configuration docs:
https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/wiki/Configuration